# Does Guice Persist provide transaction scoped or application managed EntityManager?

Tags: jpa, guice, entitymanager, guice-persist

We use [Guice Persist](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GuicePersist) to inject EntityManager in our project.

E.g.

```
public class MyDao{
   @Inject
   EntityManager em;

   public void someMethod(){
       //uses em instance
   }
}
```

But it is unclear for us how injected instance of `EntityManager` is about to be used.

1. **What type of EntityManager is this?** (see e.g.: [types of entity managers](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/)) Under the hood Guice Persist instantiates it via `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` so I'd say it's application-managed entity manager. But in [official Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JPA) they write about *seesion-per-transaction* strategy, which suggests that EntityManager is (pseudo) transaction-scoped.
2. **Should we invoke close() on it manually**? Or Guice will take care of it?
3. **What is the scope of [first level cache](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching#1st_Level_Cache)?** Only single transaction (like in transaction-scoped entity managers) or as long as I use the same injected instance of `EntityManager` (like in application managed entity managers)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did some research of the source code of Guice-persist and read through comments under Guice-persist wiki pages and these are the answers that I needed:

1 . Lifecycle management of EntityManager is kind of broken if it's injected via @Inject EntityManager. As stated in one of the comments on the Wiki:

> I confirm that inject directly an EntityManager instead of a provider
>   can be dangerous. If you're not inside a UnitOfWork or a method
>   annotated with @Transaction, the first injection of an EntityManager
>   in a thread will create a new EntityManager, never destroy it, and
>   always use this specific EntityManager for this thread (EM are stored
>   thread-local). This can lead to terrible issues, like injection of
>   dead entityManager (connection closed, etc) So my recommendation if to
>   always inject a Provider, or at least to inject
>   directly an EntityManager only inside an opened UnitOfWork.

So example in my question isn't the most correct usage. It creates singleton instance of EntityManager (per-thread) and will inject this instance everywhere :-(.

However if I've injected Provider and used it inside @Transactional method then the instance of EntityManager would be per-transaction. So the answer to this question is: **if injected and used correctly, the entity manager is transaction-scoped**.

2 . **If injected and used correctly then I don't need to manualy close entity manager** (guice-persist will handle that for me). If used incorrectly, closing manually would be very bad idea (closed instance of EntityManager would be injected in every place when I @Inject EntityManager )

3 . **If injected and used correctly then the scope of L1 cache is single transaction**. If used incorrectly, the scope of the L1 cache is the lifetime of application (EntityManager is singleton)

Answer (score 31):

Even though the question is perfectly answered by Piotr I'd like to add some practical advise on how to use guice-persist.

I've been having issues with it which were pretty hard to debug. In my application certain threads would display outdated data and sometimes `EntityManager` instances were left with old dead database connections. The root cause was to be found in the way I used the `@Transactional` annotation (I only used them for methods that do updates/inserts/deletes, not for read-only methods). guice-persist stores `EntityManager` instances in a `ThreadLocal` as soon as you call `get()` on an injected `Provider<EntityManager>` instance (which I did for read-only methods). However, this `ThreadLocal` is only removed if you also call `UnitOfWork.end()` (which normally is done by the interceptor if `@Transactional` is on the method). Not doing so will leave the EM instance in the ThreadLocal so that eventually every thread in your thread pool will have an old EM instance with stale cached entities.

So, as long as you stick to the following simple rules the usage of guice-persist is straight forward:

1. Always inject `Provider<EntityManager>` instead of `EntityManager` directly.
2. For transaction-scoped semantics: always annotate each method with `@Transactional` (even the read-only methods). This way the `JpaLocalTxnInterceptor` will intercept the calls to your annotated methods making sure not only to start and commit transactions but also to set and unset EM instances in the ThreadLocal.
3. For request-scoped semantics: use the `PersistFilter` servlet filter that ships with guice-persist. It will call `begin()` and `end()` on the `UnitOfWork` for you before and after the request is done, thereby populating and cleaning up the ThreadLocal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great advice RE the use of transactional. I was doing the exact same thing so you have just solved my problem.

Comment: Ditto - wasted hours on this. @Transactional solved it for me.

Comment: This is a HUGE design flaw in Guice-persist!

Even a small mistake (use EntityManager outside @Transactional) corrupts your whole project with difficult bugs ...

For example; my Google App Engine project started to generate JDBC connection timeouts after eight hours due to pending/stale network connections. The reason (after long debugging) was one "pEntityManagerProvider.get()" without @Transactional in a utility class ...

Answer (score 6):

1. It depends on you module cofiguration. There are some basic bindings:

**JpaPersistanceService**

```
public class JpaPersistanceService implements Provider<EntityManager> {

  private EntityManagerFactory factory;

  public JpaPersistanceService(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  @Override
  public EntityManager get() {
    return factory.createEntityManager();
  }
}
```

**Module binding**

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(getEnvironment(stage));
bind(EntityManager.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("request")).toProvider(new JpaPersistanceService(factory)).in(RequestScoped.class);
bind(EntityManager.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("session")).toProvider(new JpaPersistanceService(factory)).in(SessionScoped.class);
bind(EntityManager.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("app")).toProvider(new JpaPersistanceService(factory)).asEagerSingleton;
```

**Usage**

```
@Inject @Named("request")
private EntityManager em; //inject a new EntityManager class every request

@Inject @Named("session")
private Provider<EntityManager> emProvider; //inject a new EntityManager class each session
//This is little bit tricky, cuz EntityManager is stored in session. In Stage.PRODUCTION are all injection created eagerly and there is no session at injection time. Session binding should be done in lazy way - inject provider and call emProvider.get() when em is needed;

@Inject @Named("application")
private EntityManager em; //inject singleton
```

2. Yes, you should or you will use [JpaPersistModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502271/best-way-to-initialize-jpapersistmodule) [[javadoc]](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html)

3. Well, this is about JPA configuration in persistence.xml and EntityManager scope

Answer (score 0):

I'm injecting a provider .... but I suspect something is wrong.
When I try to redeploy an application ALWAYS I have to restar the server because the JPA classes are cached.

It happens the following pseudo-bug

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326552

Theoretically by injecting a Provider and getting an instance of EntityManager you should not close anything ....