# Guice DAO Provider in thread pool - queries become 'idle in transation'

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, transactions, guice

I use Java 8, Hibernate 5.1.0.Final and Guice 4.1.0.

```
@Inject
private Provider<ExampleDAO> exampleDAOProvider;

public void test(){

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                logger.info(exampleDAOProvider.find(1l));

            }
        });

    threadPool.shutdown();

}
```

Every `test()` method execution will produce 10 (thread pool size) rows more in `pg_stat_activity`. They are simple `select * from` queries which have `idle in transaction` state and never disappear. So I reach `hibernate.c3p0.max_size` limit and my application stops working with database.

Database module:

```
public class ExampleModule extends PrivateModule {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        install(new JpaPersistModule("example-persistence-unit").properties(jpaProperties()));

        bind(ExampleDAO.class).to(ExampleDAOImpl.class);

        expose(ExampleDAO.class);

        Key<PersistFilter> key = Key.get(PersistFilter.class, ExamplePersistenceUnit.class);
        bind(key).to(PersistFilter.class);
        expose(key);
    }
}
```

I have tried to `@Inject Provider<ExampleDAO> exampleDAOProvider` into the task class code but it does not change anything. If I `@Inject exampleDAO`, then I face concurrency issues (`ConcurrentModificationException`) because it uses the same `EntityManager`.

If I use  `@Inject Provider<ExampleDAO> exampleDAOProvider` or direct `@Inject ExampleDAO exampleDAO` without multithreading, it works well and connections get released.

Why does it happen? How to get connections released in the multithreaded code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have annotated almost every DAO method with `@Transactional` and this seems to solve my problem. After processing, transactions are committed and connections released. Didn't mark as `@Transactional` methods which query entities which should be persisted later in the same `EntityManager` or `Session` to avoid using `merge()`. Please note that `@Transactional` works only for public methods and `synchronized` doesn't work with `@Transactional`.

GenericDAOImpl use `@Inject Provider<EntityManager>` instead of `@Inject EntityManager`:

```
@Inject
protected Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;

private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManagerProvider.get();
}
```

Related discussion: [Does Guice Persist provide transaction scoped or application managed EntityManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101488/does-guice-persist-provide-transaction-scoped-or-application-managed-entitymanag)

---

**UDPATE 1**

Another things to check:

- If you're using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final, then persistence.xml should contain:

`<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />`

Instead of:

`<property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />`

**UDPATE 2**

If you're using

`<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />`

it may cause connection leaks when lazy loading. Related discussions:

- [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574236/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sess)
- [Solve Hibernate Lazy-Init issue with hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362831/solve-hibernate-lazy-init-issue-with-hibernate-enable-lazy-load-no-trans/25367976#25367976)

Comment: I have posted this because it solves my problem. However, any comments about implementation are appreciated.