# How to prevent reuse of EntityManager with guice-persist and @Transactional?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, guice, guice-persist

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101488/does-guice-persist-provide-transaction-scoped-or-application-managed-entitymanag/18185805), when using `guice-persist`, `EntityManager` is transaction-scoped. If I understand correctly, this means that a new `EntityManager` will be created for every transaction. When using `guice-persist`, it is suggested to use `JpaPersistModule`, which provides all the bindings, and simply inject `Provider<EntityManager>` into some class, like this:

```
public class ProjectDAO {

  private final Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;

  @Inject
  public ProjectDAO(Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider) {

    this.entityManagerProvider = entityManagerProvider;
  }
}
```

**Note**: in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18196603/1720112) it says that `EntityManager` should not be injected directly, but to use `Provider<EntityManager>` instead, to avoid this [issue](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/739), therefore the injection of `Provider<EntityManager>`. Also, by looking at the code for [JpaPersistService](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/extensions/persist/src/com/google/inject/persist/jpa/JpaPersistService.java), `EntityManager` instances are stored in a `ThreadLocal`. At the same time, `@Transactional` annotation and its `JpaLocalTxnInterceptor` counterpart should ensure that `.set()` and `.remove()` are called on `ThreadLocal<EntityManager>` field after every transaction.

Now, I've tried this and every thread has its own `EntityManager`. However, it seems like it is not removed and set again, but reused for subsequent transactions, i.e. Hibernate's first level cache is not cleared.

Here's a complete example that inserts and deletes some entities from two different threads (sequentially, not in parallel), which leads to one thread having stale information:

**Project** (a simple entity)

```java
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "project.findAll", query = "from project"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "project.deleteByProjectName", query = "delete from project p where p.name = :project_name")
    }
    )
    @Entity(name = "project")
    public class Project {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;

        // ... getters/setters
    }
```

**ProjectDAO**

```java
    public class ProjectDAO {

      private final Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;

      @Inject
      public ProjectDAO(Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider) {
        this.entityManagerProvider = entityManagerProvider;
      }

      public void insert(Project project) {
        entityManagerProvider.get().persist(project);
      }

      public List<Project> findAll() {

        return entityManagerProvider.get()
            .createNamedQuery("project.findAll", Project.class)
            .getResultList();
      }

      public void delete(String projectName) {

        entityManagerProvider.get()
            .createNamedQuery("project.deleteByProjectName")
            .setParameter("project_name", projectName)
            .executeUpdate(); 
      }

      public Project findById(Long id) {

        return entityManagerProvider.get().find(Project.class, id);
      }
    }
```

**ProjectService**

```java
    public class ProjectService {

      private final ProjectDAO projectDAO;

      @Inject
      public ProjectService(ProjectDAO projectDAO) {

        this.projectDAO = projectDAO;
      }

      @Transactional
      public void addProject(Project project) {
        projectDAO.insert(project);
      }

      @Transactional
      public List<Project> findAll() {
        return projectDAO.findAll();
      }

      @Transactional
      public void delete(String projectName) {
        projectDAO.delete(projectName);
      }

      @Transactional
      public Project findById(Long id) {
        return projectDAO.findById(id);
      }

      public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return projectDAO.getEntityManager();
      }
    }
```

**Main class**

```java
    public class Start {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
          @Override 
          protected void configure() {
            install(new JpaPersistModule("hibernatetesting"));
            bind(ProjectService.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
          }
        });

        ProjectService projectService = injector.getInstance(ProjectService.class);
        PersistService persistService = injector.getInstance(PersistService.class);

        persistService.start();

        // For the purpose of making transactions from different threads, we
        // create two single threaded executors
        ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        ExecutorService executorService2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        // Execute a few queries from Thread 1
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);

        executorService1.execute(() -> {
        System.out.println("TEST: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("TEST: " +"EntityManager: " + projectService.getEntityManager().hashCode());
          projectService.addProject(new Project("project1"));
          projectService.addProject(new Project("project2"));
          countDownLatch1.countDown();
        });

        countDownLatch1.await();


        // Execute a few queries from Thread 2
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch2 = new CountDownLatch(1);

        executorService2.execute(() -> {
          System.out.println("TEST: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          System.out.println("TEST: " +"EntityManager: " + projectService.getEntityManager().hashCode());
          projectService.addProject(new Project("project3"));
          projectService.addProject(new Project("project4"));

          //----
          projectService.delete("project1");
          //----

          // project3 is not shown in this list
          projectService.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
          countDownLatch2.countDown();
        });

        countDownLatch2.await();

        // Execute a few more queries from Thread 1
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch3 = new CountDownLatch(1);

        executorService1.execute(() -> {
          System.out.println("TEST: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          System.out.println("TEST: " +"EntityManager: " + projectService.getEntityManager().hashCode());
          projectService.addProject(new Project("project5"));
          projectService.addProject(new Project("project6"));

          // project3, which was deleted in Thread 2 is still visible in
          // this EntityManager
          // ----
          Project project = projectService.findById(3L);
          System.out.println("Project still exists " + project);
          // ----

          projectService.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
          countDownLatch3.countDown();
        });

        countDownLatch3.await();

      }
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
    ...
    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-persist</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    ...
```

**persistence.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="hibernatetesting" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

      <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB"/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />

      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

1) Is this the usual way of using EntityManager with guice-persist and working around the fact that different threads might have different state?

2) If not, how to make sure that EntityManager is re-set on the ThreadLocal after each transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the above code:

1) The following line

```java
System.out.println("TEST: " +"EntityManager: " + projectService.getEntityManager().hashCode());
```

was added for debugging purposes. However, the method `ProjectService.getEntityManager()`, which calls `ProjectDAO.getEntityManager()`, which in turn calls `entityManagerProvider.get()`, is not annotated with `@Transactional`. This causes `EntityManager` to be set once per thread and never unset, even though other methods from ProjectService that have the `@Transactional` annotation are called later. Simply adding this annotation solves the problem.

2) In one thread, entity with name "project1" was deleted

```java
   //----
   projectService.delete("project1");
   //----
```

however, in the other thread, presence is verified for another entity

```java
   // project3, which was deleted in Thread 2 is still visible in this EntityManager
   Project project = projectService.findById(3L);
   System.out.println("Project still exists " + project);
```

which was never deleted in the first place. Entities are added one by one - project1, project2, project3... and they are assigned IDs 1, 2, 3... respectively. So the code should be

```java
   // project1, which was deleted in Thread 2 is still visible in this EntityManager
   Project project = projectService.findById(1L);
   System.out.println("Project still exists " + project);
```