# How to create a RESTful API with Jersey + Grizzly + Guice + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jersey, guice

I've spent some time trying to create a RESTful API with Jersey, Grizzly, Guice and Hibernate, and I'm having a very difficult time wrapping my head around how to wire everything together. This is what I've been able to figure out on my own.

- I have a working DAO that implements a simple interface. I'm using Guice to inject here. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576510/how-to-prevent-reuse-of-entitymanager-with-guice-persist-and-transactional) as a reference.

  ```java
   public class ProjectDAO implements ProjectDAOGeneric {
       private final Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;

       @Inject
       public ProjectDAO(Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider) {
         this.entityManagerProvider = entityManagerProvider;
       }

       @Transactional
       public void insert(Project project) {
         entityManagerProvider.get().persist(project);
       }

   // (...)
  ```

---

- I created a very simple CRUD API with Jersey. I used this [course I found on PluralSight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/build-asynchronous-restful-services-jersey/) for help.

  ```java
   @Path("/project")
   public class ProjectResource {

       private final ProjectDAOGeneric projectDAO;

       @Inject
       public ProjectResource(ProjectDAOGeneric projectDAO) {
         this.projectDAO = projectDAO;
       }

       @GET
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       public List<Project> getProjects() {
         return projectDAO.findAll();
       }

   // (...)
  ```

---

- From what I understand, [I have to bridge Guice and HK2](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/guice-bridge) so that both of them work together. I have something like this.

  ```java
  public class HK2toGuiceModule extends AbstractBinder {

    private Injector guiceInjector;

    public HK2toGuiceModule(Injector guiceInjector) {
      this.guiceInjector = guiceInjector;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bindFactory(new ServiceFactory<ProjectService>(guiceInjector, ProjectService.class)).to(ProjectService.class);
    }

    private static class ServiceFactory<T> implements Factory<T> {
      private final Injector guiceInjector;
      private final Class<T> serviceClass;

      public ServiceFactory(Injector guiceInjector, Class<T> serviceClass) {
        this.guiceInjector = guiceInjector;
        this.serviceClass = serviceClass;
      }

      @Override
      public T provide() {
        return guiceInjector.getInstance(serviceClass);
      }

      @Override
      public void dispose(T versionResource) {
      }

  }
  ```

---

- After that, I can create a simple Guice Module to bind the `ProjectDAO` interface to its implementation.

  ```java
  public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(ProjectDAOGeneric.class).to(ProjectDAO.class);
    }
  }
  ```

---

- I imagine that we would then need to create a `ResourceConfig` to initialize Grizzly, also taking the Guice bridge into consideration. I have something like this.

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Config extends ResourceConfig {

  @Inject
  public Config(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
    packages("com.myproject");
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule());
    initGuiceIntoHK2Bridge(serviceLocator, injector);
  }

  private void initGuiceIntoHK2Bridge(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, Injector injector) {
    GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
    GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
    guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
  }

}
```

---

- I figure that the last step would be to use that `ResourceConfig` in order to initialize the Grizzly `HttpServer`.

```java
public class Main {

    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";

    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.myproject");
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), config);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

      // (...)
```

Now, **I can't figure out how to do this.** The only code I have here is the one that Grizzly provides by default. I'm not sure how to use the custom `ResourceConfig` I created.

---

Most of what I found online was +5 years old, and [the most relevant post on StackOverflow asking about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669926/practical-advice-on-using-jersey-and-guice-for-restful-service) is 12 years old at this point. So I figured that either Google is not being very helpful or I'm missing something. I can't seem to figure it out on my own, and I definitely haven't been able to find any up-to-date resources about it.

With all this, I have two simple questions:

- Does my current approach even make sense?
- If it does, how can I connect everything together? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have your `Config` class but aren't using it. You're create the server with a completely different `ResourceConfig`. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35085267/2587435)